# How can I Execute one line of code for once in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a code which reverse the equation from infix notation into postfix notation .. also that code does Evaluate the equation, My problem is when I add the evaluation code which is "Y is Equation" the program returns me the evaluation correct but the revers of the equation is wrong, here is my code:

```
fact(A + B, A, B, +).
fact(A - B, A, B, -).
fact(A * B, A, B, *).
fact(A / B, A, B, /).


topostfix(Equation, X,Y) :-  
    % y is Equation , -- I want to execute this line for once --
    fact(Equation, A, B, Op),
    !,
    topostfix(A, AA),
    topostfix(B, BB),
    append(AA, BB, CC),
    append(CC, [Op], X).
    topostfix(X, [X]).
```

Comment: Your question is not clear as the `is/2` built-in predicate is deterministic. Can you post sample queries that illustrate the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't just have a typo (lower case y instead of upper case Y). The code runs fine with `Y is Equation`. The postfixing doesn't work properly yet, but that seems to be a different problem.

Comment: Thank you :) Paulo Moura has solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you're making a `topostfix/2` predicate calls instead of recursive calls to `topostfix/3`. Try:

```
fact(A + B, A, B, +).
fact(A - B, A, B, -).
fact(A * B, A, B, *).
fact(A / B, A, B, /).

topostfix(Equation, X, Y) :-  
    Y is Equation,
    fact(Equation, A, B, Op),
    !,
    topostfix(A, AA, _),
    topostfix(B, BB, _),
    append(AA, BB, CC),
    append(CC, [Op], X).
topostfix(X, [X], X).
```

For example:

```
?- topostfix(2 + 3, X, Y).
X = [2, 3, +],
Y = 5.

?- topostfix(2 + 3 * 5, X, Y).
X = [2, 3, 5, *, +],
Y = 17.
```